# Hide and Show angular 4 component depending on route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi there Im not sure if this is possible... basically I want to be able to show a component but only if the route matches and hide a component if the route matches Ive tried this `app-header-home` shows when the route is `'/'`which is good but `app-header` doesnt show at all even when the route inst `'/'` how can I fix this?

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header *ngIf="router.url == '/'"><app-header>
<app-header-home *ngIf="router.url != '/'"></app-header-home> //component I want hidden unless url '/'
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {

  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

check the `router.url` in the template:

```
<app-header><app-header>
<app-header-home *ngIf="router != '/ur_route'"></app-header-home> //component I want hidden unless url /home
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in `app.component.ts` inject the `router`.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  router: string;

  constructor(private _router: Router){

          this.router = _router.url; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ive tried what you said and It doesnt seem to be working?

Comment: no errors in the console ive updated my question with the new code

Comment: Im getting this error `[ts] Property 'router' does not exist on type 'AppComponent' did you mean '_router'?`

Comment: also how can I do the opposite for `app-header` only show if the route isnt '/'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160759/discussion-between-a61nn5-and-sachila-ranawaka).

Comment: This doesn't work if you use a shared component view inside view

Comment: Assigning just the url to `this.router` in the constructor didn't work for me.  I had to assign the router instance: `this.router = _router;` and then call the url from the if condition `*ngIf="router.url != '/ur_route'"`.  PS, the `router` property will also need to be changed from type `string` to type `Router`.

Answer (score 22):

This is in reference to the comment posted by `SUNIL JADHAV`. Instead of exposing the router handle on the templates we can define it inside a function and call it in the template.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  /**
   * Check if the router url contains the specified route
   *
   * @param {string} route
   * @returns
   * @memberof MyComponent
   */
  hasRoute(route: string) {
    return this.router.url.includes(route);
  }
}
```

Then in the html file we can use it like so

```html
<!-- First view -->
<div *ngIf="hasRoute('home')">
    First View
</div>

<!-- Second view activated when the route doesn't contain the home route -->
<div *ngIf="!hasRoute('home')">
    Second View
</div>
```

Comment: I like how this encapsulates the the router instead of exposing it to the template. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer didn't work, because i think the variable will be assigned only once, then when we navigate, that variable will not be updated (component already initialized).

here's how I did it.. We inject the router in the component we want to hide  :

```
constructor(private _router: Router){}
```

then in our template :

```
<div *ngIf="_router.url != '/login'">
  ... your component html ...
</div>
```

Comment: I get this build error: Property 'router' is private and only accessible within class

Comment: @Harsimer You need to change it to `public` to use it in the template.

Answer (score 4):

Below code worked for me.

I am hiding side navigation in login screen.

```
 <div *ngIf="!router.url.includes('login')"  class="sidenav">
```

Comment: Bad practice to use functions inside html template

Comment: @szymeo - not always true, it's okay to use functions in templates. The reason it's bad is the the function will be called on every change detection update, where as a variable would only be compared. So calling a function that connects to service to fetch data would be terrible, but calling a function that returns a quick local variable wouldn't be harmful. So use at your descretion and don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: @LocustHorde it's true that it's a bad practice, because disabled ngZone is not a default setting. It's not always bad, but considering majority of developers aren't that much into Angular's CD, it's easier to just assume that it's always bad. Simplicity for life, although agree with you