# Angular how to hide a global component when a specific route is opened?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular7-router

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not in angular but I wanted to hide a global component when a specific route is opened.

Say for example I have the following:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-banner></app-banner> <!-- Global Component I want to hide -->

<div class="body-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { StudentListComponent } from './Components/StudentList/StudentList.component';
import { SchoolMottoComponent } from './Components/SchoolMotto/SchoolMotto.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'StudentList', component: StudentListComponent },
    {path: 'SchoolMotto', component: SchoolMottoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [StudentListComponent, SchoolMottoComponent]
```

With this, its a given that when I want to view the StudentList Component, then the url by default becomes localhost4200:/StudentList and the same with SchoolMotto it becomes localhost4200:/SchoolMotto.

Within the StudentListComponent, is an ag-grid that displays  list of students, and when you click one of those students the url becomes something like this: localhost4200:/StudentList/view/cf077d79-a62d-46e6-bd94-14e733a5939d and its another sub-component of SchoolList that displays the details of that particular student.

I wanted to hide the Global banner component when the url has something like that: localhost4200:/StudentList/view/cf077d79-a62d-46e6-bd94-14e733a5939d. Only when the user views the specific details of a student.

Something like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>

**<app-banner *ngIf="router != '/StudentList/view/'"></app-banner> <!-- Global Component I want to hide -->**

<div class="body-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Is this doable or not? If it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use event emitter or subject to emit an event when you're in `StudentList/view` and use ngIf to hide the banner.

In your StudentList `component.ts` :

```
export class StudentList {
bannerSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
ngOnInit() {
         bannerSubject.next(true);
    }
}
```

subscribe to this in your parent component and you can easily hide the banner.

Comment: Edited my answer because your url can be dynamic

Comment: How do you do it using event Emitters?

Comment: see [this](https://alligator.io/angular/outputs-angular/)

Answer (score 1):

You can acheieve that with the help of `component interation` using a `service`

You will use the help of `Rxjs Observables` here

You will emit an event when you reach the `student view component`, then recieve that event in `app component` then change the view condition

**New Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RouteService {

  private routeChangedSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  routeChanged$ = this.routeChangedSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  changeRoute(mission: string) {
    this.routeChangedSource.next(mission);
  }
}
```

**Student View Component.**

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

import { routeService }     from './mission.service';

@Component({
})
export class MissionControlComponent implements ngOnInit{
  constructor(private routeService: routeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeService.changeRoute(mission);
  }
}
```

**App Component:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { RouteService } from './route.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs';


export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  studentView = false;
  constructor(private routeService: RouteService) {
    this.subscription = routeService.routeChanged$.subscribe(
      value => {
        this.studentView = true;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Now, your **App Component** can be:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-banner *ngIf="!studentView"></app-banner>

<div class="body-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-banner *ngIf="myService.hideGlobalComp"></app-banner> <!-- Global Component I want to hide -->

<div class="body-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in the ts file:

```
onCellClicked($event) { // place into your method there you want. 

    this.route.parent.url.subscribe(urlPath => {
      this.url = urlPath[urlPath.length - 1].path;
    });

   if(this.url === 'StudentList/view') {
  this.myService.hideGlobalComp = true;
}

}

}
```

Comment: this URL part is a cf077d79-a62d-46e6-bd94-14e733a5939d is dynamic its change every time

Answer (score -1):

In you ts file do like this.

1. add new variable `router: string;`
2. add in construction add this

`constructor(private _router: Router){
   this.router = _router.url; 
 }`

Then in HTML use same code.
Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: why downvote.. check this url - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707225/hide-and-show-angular-4-component-depending-on-route, I provided same solution.

Comment: you are just down voting it without any comment.