# Check which component is displayed depending on the router-outlet

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-components, router-outlet, angular-component-router

I have the following app.component.html structure:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I'm trying to change the appearance of the website depending on the component that is displayed.

For instance, let's say I don't won't to show the footer if the router-outlet displays a certain component (or the opposite: I want to show the footer if a certain/s component/s are shown).

Is there a way to check which component is being displayed based on the router-outlet and then set up the conditions?

Comment: are you trying to show and hide components based on routes ?

Comment: Yes! Also, if I could be able to receive information from the router-outlet it would be nice, but I guess the routes approach works as well!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707225/hide-and-show-angular-4-component-depending-on-route